# Twilio Fax 'confirmation page' - how to make it legally binding

Tags: twilio, confirmation, fax

Faxes are considered more legal then email using the confirmation page spit out by the fax machine.

I don't know why that sheet of paper can be trusted by a court as it can be produced by any semi savvy computer user. I see that efax claims their faxes are legally binding.

Is there any way to get a legal binding confirmation from Twilio's fax?

The status callback does not seem adequate. Does Twilio, as a third party, provide a way to date stamp the document or first page?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the status callback is the only thing we provide in terms of a confirmation. Whether that is legally binding or not is a question for your lawyer.

We also do not provide a way to timestamp the front page as part of the API.